# How to Make a Direct download link of an embedded Video

Tags: html, url, browser, hyperlink

I have a Souce URL of a .MP4 video
here is the URL: http://naruto.manga47.net/Naruto_Dub/040.MP4

to download this video we have to *open the link and wait for it to load and then we will be able to
download it by right-clicking on it and saving it as a video*.

the Question is That ** I want to get a Direct download link of this video. After pasting the Direct link in a browser it will start downloading the video without any second click**

please tell me if this is even possible.
-Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can use  tag to do this. I suspect somewhere in your code you have an  link to this address. Just put a download tag after it like this:

`<a href="/download/Naruto_Dub/040.MP4" download>`

or like this:

`<a href="/download/Naruto_Dub/040.MP4" download="Naruto Video">`

and then it will tell the browser to download the file in that link. For more in-depth info read here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

EDIT: Chrome 65+ and Firefox only support same-origin download links, due to security reasons. You would need to download the file yourself, and put it somewhere on your website and then link it to your own website.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The a download attribute</h1>

<p>Click on the image to download it:<p>
<a href="http://naruto.manga47.net/Naruto_Dub/040.MP4" download>
  <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in IE or Edge (prior version 18), or in Safari (prior version 10.1).</p>

</body>
</html>


------------------------------

NO This method is not working

Comment: Sorry about that. On the site, I linked it says that Chrome 65+ and Firefox only support same-origin download links. I just edited my answer with some more information

Comment: <a href="/download/Naruto_Dub/040.MP4" download="Naruto Video">

this code is downloading the HTML DOCUMENT,
i know i can download and create a link to download it,
i was searching for direct download

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I try this I directly download the mp4 file when I click the link. Here is a test page I made on my own website, to show how I implemented it: http://jorianwoltjer.tk/sof/a_download

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/SWcGL7z.png
see above link, Its downloading the html page ,its not downloading the actual .mp4 file

Comment: Hmmm, that's weird. This looks like a browser problem since for me it works just fine. Maybe edit your question to this, since this is way more interesting and I don't know the answer myself

Comment: bro its not a browser problem ,try to download that video with your link,after downloading is done, try to play it and then tell me what is happening

Comment: I just realized what the problem is! I had the download cached in my browser so it wouldn't actually download the file. When I just cleared my browser cache I get the same problem as you do. Then I saw that the `href` in the <a> is not actually going to the file, because after downloading it, it renamed the extension to `.mp4` instead of `.MP4`. Now on my site it works fine. If you want to have it on your site too, make sure that the link actually goes to the file with the right extension and it should work

Comment: It is not making sense for me ,can you please explain it in steps?

Comment: Sure, just try to click the link on **your** website without the download attribute. That will likely take you to a 404 page, since the extension is wrong. Now go to the file on your server and change the extension of it from mp4 to MP4. Then the link you made at the start should take you to the video. Now just add back the download attribute and boom! You have your download link

Comment: Thanks, bro for helping me this much wanna be friends?

Comment: Haha, sure. You can add me on Discord if you ever have any further problems. My tag is Jorian#3980

Answer (score 0):

So basically you have a direct link of a file on internet, That is this : http://naruto.manga47.net/Naruto_Dub/040.MP4

the easiest thing you can do is just add   ?dl=1   at last in the link in order to download it.

Now the link will be :
http://naruto.manga47.net/Naruto_Dub/040.MP4?dl=1

Comment: not working in chrome with s3 video link.